# spark stand alone cluster jar not found

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark stand alone cluster with one master and 2 worker nodes. (hope im not mistaken the terms). all are centos
I have a shared folder containing text file and a share folder for all the result file. Im not using hdfs...
I also have a folder on the master containg wordcount.jar file...
I want to run word count agains a file in the shared folder...
when i run spark-submit with deploy-mode client pointing to the wordcount.jar on the master everything works fine but when i use deploy-mode cluster i get an error wordcount.jar not found...
why? how do i fix it?
i though the jar file is distributed across the cluster...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Include the driver classpath when you are executing in Cluster mode.

```
--driver-class-path $JARS_COLON_SEP \
```

Comment: I have includded the class path.. not solve the problem